# Interpreting recurrent neural networks features (RNN/LSTM)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, shap

I tried to use shap in order to do a feature importance analysis. I am using keras and I want to get a bar chart and violin charts. With my DNN, I got something like that:
[Violin chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0CK8.png)
[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbd3k.png)

However, when I tried it with my SimpleRNN, I had problem with the shape. The input shape is (samples,time,features), whereas my output shape is (samples,features). So it is a many-to-one RNN. KernelExplainer, the one that I used in my static models, does not work because of the dimension. DeepExplainer does not work either. It show me this error:

```
Your TensorFlow version is newer than 2.4.0 and so graph support has been removed in eager mode. See PR #1483 for discussion.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..."
    ... = model.predict(data)
  File "...", line 103, in predict
    explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(self.model, self.background)
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/shap/explainers/_deep/__init__.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.explainer = TFDeep(model, data, session, learning_phase_flags)
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/shap/explainers/_deep/deep_tf.py", line 131, in __init__
    self.graph = _get_graph(self)
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/shap/explainers/tf_utils.py", line 46, in _get_graph
    return explainer.model_output.graph
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

Do you know what this error could be due to?
Here I have seen people with similar problems with shap and LSTM, but there is no a clear solution. Do you recommend an alternative method to shap to get those charts?

my tensorflow version is 2.4.1 and my shap version is 0.38.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding at the beginning of my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Shap does not work with 2.4.1 tensorflow version